# Cannot deduce type of indirectly called template function

Tags: c++, function, templates

The following code fragment is a stripped-down version of what should become an optimization algorithm:

```
template<typename F>
double helper(F f, double x)
{
    return x;
}

template<typename F, typename L>
double optimize(F f, double x, L line_search)
{
    double y = line_search(f, x);
    return y;
}

int main()
{
    auto f = [](double x){ return (x - 2) * (x - 2); };
    double solution = optimize(f, -2, helper);
}
```

I parametrized the main function (`optimize`) and the helper function (`helper`) with a template argument `F` for the function they are trying to minimize. However, the code doesn't compile; the compiler cannot figure out the type of `line_search`:

```
t04.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
t04.cpp:17:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘optimize(main()::<lambda(double)>&, int, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
     double solution = optimize(f, -2, helper);
                                             ^
t04.cpp:8:8: note: candidate: template<class F, class L> double optimize(F, double, L)
 double optimize(F f, double x, L line_search)
        ^~~~~~~~
t04.cpp:8:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
t04.cpp:17:45: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘L’
     double solution = optimize(f, -2, helper);
```

(I am using gcc v7.5.0, but I don't think it matters here.) I think I understand why the compiler doesn't know the type of `line_search` (it doesn't look inside `optimize` to see how `line_search` is called), but I don't know how to explain it what the correct type should be. I wish I could say `optimize(f, -2, helper<type of f>)`, but I didn't find how to do this. What do I need to change to the code?

Incidentally, if there are other, equally generic ways of designing this but that avoid the template argument deduction problem, I would be interested to learn about them.

Comment: `helper` is a function template.  Which specialization of `helper` should the compiler us in `optimize(f, -2, helper)`?

Comment: Why is helper a template? It doesn't do anything with f. If there IS a reason, then you could possibly do like `optimize(f, -2, helper<decltype(f)>)`.

Comment: @ScottHutchinson: You are right that in this example, the template parameter is unused. The idea is that there could be several helpers (line search methods, actually), that all perform the same task of minimizing a function `f` of a single variable. `decltype` is actually what I was looking for without knowing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a default type for `L` which includes `F`:

```
template<typename F>
double helper(F f, double x) {
    return f(x);
}

template<typename F, typename L = double(*)(F, double)>  // <- here
double optimize(F f, double x, L line_search) {
    double y = line_search(f, x);
    return y;
}
```

It will then find the correct template instantiation when you do

```
double solution = optimize(f, -2, helper);   // helper is helper<decltype(f)>
```

If `helper` is a function template you use often, you can make it the default:

```
template<typename F, typename L = double(*)(F, double)>
double optimize(F f, double x, L line_search = helper<F>) {  // <- here
    double y = line_search(f, x);
    return y;
}
```

which makes it possible to call `optimize` without specifying the helper:

```
double solution = optimize(f, -2);   // helper<decltype(f)> is the default
```